# How to solve "CommandNotFoundException" error in Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm working on an Electron project. By the command of [this tutorial](https://medium.com/folkdevelopers/the-ultimate-guide-to-electron-with-react-8df8d73f4c97), I added this script in the `package.json` file: `"electron-dev": "electron ."`
When I try to use the script to run the app, however, the app has nothing but the color #282c34 specified in the `App.css` file, and the console prints this error:

```
(node:13384) electron: Failed to load URL: http://localhost:3000/ with error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(Use `electron --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

After I use `electron --trace-warnings ...`, I get this:

```
electron : The term 'electron' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. 
At line:1 char:1
+ electron --trace-warnings ...
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (electron:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Does anyone know how to help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the command from the command line (PowerShell it seems to be in your case), you'd have to create a new script in your `package.json` like the following:

```json
{
    // ...
    "scripts": {
        "electron-dev": "electron .",
        "electron-trace": "electron --trace-warnings ."
    },
    // ...
}
```

The rest of your file should be left untouched. What the `...` in the command shown wanted to show you was that you'd have to complete the command with all the other options you use. Since you only specify `.` as your app's path, that's all that's needed.

The reason you're getting the `CommandNotFoundException` is that Electron is only installed in the NPM context, and only NPM can launch it. That being said, when you added the script like I showed above, you can run it by executing:

```
npm run electron-trace
```

Happy debugging!

Comment: Still doesn't work. It gives me the exact same error.

Comment: Exact same error as in "it throws a `CommandNotFoundException`" or as in "it tells me it can't load the page"?

Comment: The first one. I just started the whole project over with npm only (I haven't done a lot of work anyway) and it worked.